# Unable to switch iframe with src python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am cannot switch iframe in an automation code (I have to download datasets from kaggle with python, selenium). This iframe does not have an id, nor a name, just src.

I attached picture of the iframe HTML, otherwise looks like this:

```
> <iframe height="0" width="0" tabindex="-1"
> src="https://accounts.youtube.com/accounts/CheckConnection?pmpo=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com&amp;v=-1287755822&amp;timestamp=1600168651416"
> style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index:
> -1;"></iframe>
```

My code is:

```
def access_website():
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
   driver.get('https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data?select=train.csv')
   sleep(1)

   driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div[1]/div/div[6]/div/div[2]/div").click() #click new page
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[3]/button").click()#click download dataset

    #Google login appears 
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
```

Code returns: "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector" etc"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HcZA.png)

Answer (score 0):

You use following css selector to identify the iframe.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[src^='https://accounts.youtube.com/accounts/']"))
```

---

For best practice i would suggest use `WebDriverWait`()

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://accounts.youtube.com/accounts/']")))
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: It seems to work, but when I attempt to copy the Xpath to send_keys for email + password, the same message of "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/" - is Xpath dynamically changing?

Comment: @BaptisteFernandez : That is another problem. I believe it resolved your initial problem. However if you could post the relevant HTML of username & password field that would be great

Comment: So I attempted to do it twice and both times HTML and full Xpath is the same; so although code doesn't give an error with WedDriverWait is there still a problem with it? HTML email input is: <input type="email" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="username" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="Email or phone" name="identifier" value="" autocapitalize="none" id="identifierId" dir="ltr" data-initial-dir="ltr" data-initial-value=""> Xpathcode
/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input

Comment: Worth mentioning that I tried by class_name ("whsOnd zHQkBf"), name ("identifier") and it did not work: :"Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="identifier"]"}"

Comment: It is interesting because if I use python console to do it interactively and after the failed attempts I copy paste the website link to do this: driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/identifier?response_type=code&client_ietc etc etc) 

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input").send_keys("hello")
then it works - so it really seem to be still a frame problem